# Is there a function in Racket that returns a procedure's lambda-expression?

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp, racket

In one variant of Common Lisp (I think it was CMUCL, but I might be wrong—I can't find it any more) there was a function that was (I think) called `function-lambda-expression`. If it got a procedure, it would print out the lambda expression that had generated it. Example:

```lisp
(let ((my-thunk (lambda () (+ 1 2))))
    (write my-thunk)
    (write (function-lambda-expression my-thunk)))
```

This would print out something like:

```lisp
#<PROCEDURE>
(LAMBDA () (+ 1 2))
```

It was terribly useful for debugging and exploring the language.

I'm looking for a function like this in Racket. I've looked through the [Racket Documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/index.html?q=lambda%20expression) but I can't find anything like it. (I wouldn't be surprised if I overlooked it, however.) Is there an equivalent in Racket?

Comment: Btw., in Common Lisp both `write` and `function-lambda-expression` are standard functions.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thanks! It's been a while, and I forgot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Racket's `lambda` produces a closure that does not remember its S-expression (or syntax object) form. It does typically remember its name (or its abbreviated source location, if no name can be inferred), and that's often enough to help with debugging. (See `object-name`.)

You can build your own variant of `lambda` that has this feature, using Racket's applicable structures and a simple macro. Here's a basic example:

```
#lang racket

(struct exp-closure (f exp)
  #:property prop:procedure (struct-field-index f))

(define-syntax-rule (exp-lambda formals . body)
  (exp-closure (lambda formals . body)
               (quote (exp-lambda formals . body))))

(let ([my-thunk (exp-lambda () (+ 1 2))])
  (printf "fun is ~v\n" my-thunk)
  (printf "exp is ~v\n" (exp-closure-exp my-thunk))
  (printf "result is ~v\n" (my-thunk)))
```

This produces

```
fun is #<procedure:...tmp/lambda.rkt:11:19>
exp is '(exp-lambda () (+ 1 2))
result is 3
```

A better version of this macro might propagate the source location of the macro use to the `lambda` expression it creates, or the inferred name (see `syntax-local-infer-name`), or both.

Comment: Yet another testament to Racket's flexibility and power… Thanks for not only answering the question, but giving me an alternate solution! :)